# check for similar string

Tags: c#, string

i am trying to check in a text for similar words in the range of one "wrong" char **without the contain method**, so that : "cat" = *cat,c*at,ca*t,cat*. my code is.

Here's an example:

```
string s = "the cat is here with the cagt";
int count;

string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (var item in words)
{
    if(///check for "cat")
    {
        count++;
        return count; (will return 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "similar".  This: *""cat" = gcat,cgat,cagt,catg."* tells me that, to you, "similar" means "out of place g's in a word".  Are you attempting to implement a spell checker?  There are more elegant ways than checking every possible permutation of a word, something like [the Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: What if there's one char missing, as in `cat` -> `at`?

Comment: the "g" is just an example ... it could be any letter.
if one char is missing then no good . :)

Comment: Why don't you want to use the contains method..? what are you truly trying to accomplish..? makes no sense also the code you have there what are you going to check against..? a char or a word..?

Comment: @zipo_soft: Kind of my point.

Comment: also looking at that code.. how will count++ ever Increment..? since it's never initialized outside of the foreach loop

Comment: DJ KRAZE bcuz i need to use it on diffrent platforms.

Comment: would c*a*t also be valid?

Comment: DJ KRAZE yeah i know there'w some mistake but its not the issue..

Comment: what other platforms are you trying to use this for.. perhaps in your initial question , you need to explain that as well as formulate your question better.. this is a very poor example of an issue at best.. you have failed to answer any of the other questions. You say that you do not want to use any built in methods but in your code you are using the `Split() Method`

Comment: I'm still interested in hearing what `different platforms` the OP is wanting to use his code on..

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you wan't, but I still think a SpellCheck libary will be the way to go

```
string wordToFind = "cat";
string sentance = "the cat is here with the cagt";
int count = 0;

foreach (var word in sentance.Split(' '))
{
    if (word.Equals(wordToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    foreach (var chr in word)
    {
        if (word.Replace(chr.ToString(), "").Equals(wordToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

// returns 2
```

Comment: he wouldn't know how to use the spell check Lib based on the fact that he could have done this using a few lines of code using RegEx bur he does not want to use built in functions or methods offered out of the box with C# .NET Framework

Comment: Yeah, this is the smallest amount of "built in" functions I could think of, LOL, I should hve done in in a ridiculous Linq staement :)

Comment: actually you should it would make his head spin.. this posting should be closed.. it's truly a waste of time and would not be helpful to anyone in the future if they were to need the same type of thing in the future.. your code is exactly what I was going to post but after realizing that the OP didn't want real help I was not going to give away the obvious which was doing a nested foreach..lol

Answer (score 0):

Regexp could be the best solution. But try this out too.

```
String str = yourstring;
String s1 = 'cat';
 int cat1 = yourstring.IndexOf(s1,0);
```

Comment: Fails for two of the four examples.

Comment: tnx,  i tried that already :),  but i dont wanna use c# built in methods .

Comment: zipo_soft what are you trying to do.. perhaps you don't wanna use the built in methods because you don't understand how to use them.. is this a homework assignment..?

Comment: Well I don't understand why we use a language when we don't want to use its built in functions.... :-(  @EdS. could you please tell where it fails. Ah OP changed his string...

Comment: bonCodigo, this post should be closed.. I +1 your negative vote btw because the OP himself doesn't know what he wants he can't explain what other platforms he wants to use his code for..

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks. :-)  I believe OP is just going to migrate the code as he said. But if OP uses built in then more problems during the process. But given the other platform (if OP shared) someone here you have guided him. Yeah agree with you, he is not sure what to achieve..

Comment: @bonCodigo I agree with you but when he says other platforms then what other platforms are they.. Delphi, C, C++, Java, VB, VB.NET, C#, ect...? lol this is probably one of the worst if not worst examples of a question I have seen in 2013 less the one I saw yesterday about some OP wanting to print ***'s in a square LOL

Comment: Well for me it is best to refrain from answering vague questions next time...vague to the core perhaps... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can use regular expression for find matching.

[Regex Class MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

[C# Regex](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex)

[The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and correct but slow:

```
static bool EqualsExceptOneExtraChar(string goodStr, string strWithOneExtraChar)
{
  if (strWithOneExtraChar.Length != goodStr.Length + 1)
    return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < strWithOneExtraChar.Length; ++i)
  {
    if (strWithOneExtraChar.Remove(i, 1) == goodStr)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```